# IFormFile returning Null from an HttpClient call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am making an HttpClient call to a REST API I created. The call works fine but a part of the content is not found on the request when it hits the endpoint.

Here's my code.

Here's my method for getting the image as an IFormFile and the userId as a route param.

```
[HttpPost("UploadPhoto/{userId}")]    
public async Task UploadPhoto(IFormFile imageUpload, [FromRoute]long userId)
    {
        UploadImageCommand upload = new UploadImageCommand
        {
            UserId = userId,
            UserImage = imageUpload
        };
        var url = $"{_appSettings.OnboardingV2Url}/api/UploadPhoto/{userId}";
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        await FileClient.PostFormDataAsync<FacePatternResponse>(httpClient, url, upload);
    }
```

This is the actual method that makes the http call

```
     public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormDataAsync<T>(this HttpClient 
    httpClient, string url, UploadImageCommand data)
    {
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        foreach (var prop in data.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var value = prop.GetValue(data);
            if (value is FormFile)
            {
                var file = value as FormFile;
                content.Add(new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream()), prop.Name, file.FileName);
                content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") { Name = prop.Name, FileName = file.FileName };
            }
            else
            {
                content.Add(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value)), prop.Name);
            }
        }
        return await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
    }
```

This is the Rest API I'm trying to call. The Problem now is when i make this call the userId is populated but The imageUpload is returned as null. How do i go about resolving this?

```
    [HttpPost("UploadPhoto/{userId}")]
    public async Task UploadPhoto(IFormFile imageUpload, [FromRoute]long userId)
    {
        UploadImageCommand uploadImageCommand = new UploadImageCommand()
        {
            UserId = userId,
            UserImage = imageUpload
        };
        await _mediator.Send(uploadImageCommand);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `PostFormDataAsync` method is tried to post an object to API:

> API

Expect you have a model such as:

```cs
public class UploadImageCommand 
{
    public IFormFile UserImage { get; set; }
    // Remaining properties
}
```

For API controller, `UploadPhoto` should expect to receive a `UploadImageCommand` object and apply the `[FromForm]` attribute to it.

```cs
[HttpPost("UploadPhoto/{userId}")]
public async Task UploadPhoto([FromForm]UploadImageCommand input, [FromRoute]long userId)
{
    ...
}
```

And make sure that the `prop.Name` is with the prefix of **input** as your API to expect to receive a form-data with the name `input`.

```cs
foreach (var prop in data.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var value = prop.GetValue(data);
    if (value is FormFile)
    {
        var file = value as FormFile;
        content.Add(new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream()));
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(file .ContentType);
        content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") { Name = $"input.{prop.Name}", FileName = file.FileName };
    }
    else
    {
        content.Add(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value)), $"input.{prop.Name}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have tried but the UploadImageCommand input object on the API Controller still returns a null for both UserImage and UserId properties.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a screenshot to capture what data have been posted to API? You can check with F12 + Network tab.